# _UserManager.CreateAsync() returns sucess but does not save the user on database

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I am building a web app in .Net Core 3.0 and everything is running smooth but I found a small issue:

I have a method to create a user in a controller that runs well, saves the user and its all ok.

But I have the need to have another method in another controler that can also create users, and this method is  copy / paste from the other working method that works, uses the same UserManager that is IOC'ed, it returns sucess, but at the end the user is not in the database.

This has to be in another method as this one if for creating users for other people, where the password is auto generated. The password passes and does not give any error on the createAsync() and it complies with the settings in the startup.cs file

I have changed the method, tryed to stimulate the EF context, to check if it was something on it, but no....

```
[HttpPut]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[Route("CreateEmployee")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateEmployee([FromQuery]string email)
{

var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = email, Email = email };
var pw = UserHelper.GenerateRandomPassword(10);
var userResult = await _UserManager.CreateAsync(user, pw);
var resultRole = await _UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Employee");

var code = await _UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
"/Account/ConfirmEmail",
pageHandler: null,
values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
protocol: Request.Scheme);

EmailSender sender = new EmailSender();
await sender.SendWelcomeEmailAsync("Email Header",
new NewUserData { ConfirmUrl = callbackUrl, Password = pw, Email = email, Username = $"" });
}
```

Inspecting the object userResult :
userResult .succeded = true
uuserResult er.Errors.Count = 0

Inspecting the object resultRole :
resultRole.succeded = true
resultRole.Errors.Count = 0

Comment: I'm making a wild guess here, but are you following the password requirements?

Comment: Yep, let me post the last attempt and the password configuration options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 3; and the last password attempt that failed was " ?0H?KWXe "

Comment: Well, it looks okay. But for the sake of things, try to create the user without the password and see if it persists in the database. Just to rule out the password factor for sure. So just calling `CreateAsync(user)`

Comment: Ok will try it later and will come here with some feedback

Comment: It did not worked at all, so I refactored all.. opened an issue on Github =(